# Speed of Cleaning Text in R using a Dictionary

Tags: r, string, performance, loops, text

I currently have a list of misspellings and a list of corrections, indexed with a 1 to 1 relationship.

These corrections are specific to the work I am doing so I cannot use existing spelling correction packages.

Given a list of strings which I want to apply these corrections to, I have the following code:

```
for (i in 1:n){
  new_text <- gsub(match[i], dict[i], new_text)
  new_text <- gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', new_text)
}
```

Although this gives the results I want, it takes most of the day to run.
I cannot figure out how to use apply functions because the operations happen in a specific order on the same object.

Is there anything else I can try to speed this up?

Edit: This is the very small test set I have put together to benchmark performance.

```
match <- c("\\b(abouta|aobut|bout|abot|abotu)\\b","\\b(avdised|advisd|advized|advsied)\\b","\\b(posible|possibl)\\b","\\b(replacment|repalcement|replacemnt|replcement|rplacement)\\b","\\b(tommorrow|tomorow|tommorow|tomorro|tommoro)\\b")
dict <- c('about','advised','possible','replacement','tomorrow')
new_text <- c('be advisd replacment coming tomorow','did you get the email aobut the repalcement tomorro','the customer has been avdised of a posible replacement','there is a replacement coming tomorrow','what time tommorow is the replacment coming')
n <- 5
```

Running my current code 1000 times on this data gives 0.424 elapsed.

Comment: You should read about the powerful text mining package [`tm`](http://tm.r-forge.r-project.org/). Especially using a `SimpleCorpus` for high performance.

Comment: @KevinArseneau is this how you would do it?
`docs <- SimpleCorpus(VectorSource(new_text))
for (i in 1:n){ docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(gsub), pattern = match[i], replacement = dict[i]) 
}`

Comment: Aside from what @CallumF said, you need to provide an example tiny data set. I believe we need to benchmark your performance on the data set by running it 1000x and testing out various solutions.

Comment: @Kamil thanks for the advice, I have edited in a test set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the **corpus** library, using a custom stemmer. The library lets you provide an arbitrary `stemmer` function. In your case you would use something like the following for your stemmer:

```
library(corpus)
dict <- strsplit(split = "\\|",
    c("about" = "abouta|aobut|bout|abot|abotu",
      "advised" = "avdised|advisd|advized|advsied",
      "possible" = "posible|possibl",
      "replacement" = "replacment|repalcement|replacemnt|replcement|rplacement",
      "tomorrow" = "tommorrow|tomorow|tommorow|tomorro|tommoro"))
my_stemmer <- new_stemmer(unlist(dict), rep(names(dict), lengths(dict)))
```

Then, you can either pass this function as the `stemmer` argument to any function expecting text, or else you can create a `corpus_text` object with the stemmer attribute (as part of its `token_filter` that defines how text gets transformed to tokens):

```
new_text <- c('be advisd replacment coming tomorow',
              'did you get the email aobut the repalcement tomorro',
              'the customer has been avdised of a posible replacement',
              'there is a replacement coming tomorrow','what time tommorow is the replacment coming')
```

Use `term_stats` to count (stemmed) token occurrences:

```
text <- as_corpus_text(new_text, stemmer = my_stemmer, drop_punct = TRUE)
term_stats(text)
#>    term        count support
#> 1  replacement     5       5
#> 2  tomorrow        4       4
#> 3  the             4       3
#> 4  coming          3       3
#> 5  a               2       2
#> 6  advised         2       2
#> 7  is              2       2
#> 8  about           1       1
#> 9  be              1       1
#> 10 been            1       1
#> 11 customer        1       1
#> 12 did             1       1
#> 13 email           1       1
#> 14 get             1       1
#> 15 has             1       1
#> 16 of              1       1
#> 17 possible        1       1
#> 18 there           1       1
#> 19 time            1       1
#> 20 what            1       1
#> ⋮  (21 rows total)
```

Use `text_locate` to find instances of (stemmed) tokens in the original text:

```
text_locate(text, "replacement")
#>   text           before             instance              after            
#> 1 1                     be advisd  replacment   coming tomorow             
#> 2 2    …u get the email aobut the  repalcement  tomorro                    
#> 3 3    …been avdised of a posible  replacement                             
#> 4 4                    there is a  replacement  coming tomorrow            
#> 5 5     what time tommorow is the  replacment   coming
```

The results of the stemming function get cached, so this is all very fast.
More examples at http://corpustext.com/articles/stemmer.html